# Internet access blocked when application is in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to post some data from broadcast receiver but when my app is in background for long time, its not able to connect to internet and below error I am getting in log:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to android-guru.com/5.230.136.35 (port 80) after 90000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Even when my server is accessible from browser of same device.
It works fine when my app is in foreground or till few minutes till my app goes to background.

Comment: Could you post your receiver code?

Comment: Check you network connection please

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem today and found out it was because of "Battery Saver"/ "Battery Optimisation" was On in my Phone. After I turned it OFF internet is working.